# Can window alt+tab'ing be configured to reorder based on which window is most recently used?

Tags: keyboard

I'm having a very hard time adjusting to Ubuntu 14.04 Shift Switcher alt+tabing.  Instead of using a most recently used order of the windows, [( which is important to stay in flow )](https://www.isotoma.com/blog/2010/05/10/solving-the-real-alt-tab-problem/), the Shift Switcher is ordering the windows as it sees fit, perhaps based on the order windows were opened.

Is there a way to make the shift switcher ( or any other task switcher) alt+tab back to the last most recently used window so you can quickly switch back and forth between two windows with a single alt+tab combo at each switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install ccsm.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Open compizconfig-settings-manager with alt-F2, type ccsm.

Scroll down to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". Choose the tab "Switcher". Disable the alt-tab and shift-alt-tab key bindings. ("Key to start the switcher" and "Key to switch to the previous window in the Switcher".
Click the "Back" button.

Scroll down to the "Window management" section. Here you can select another switcher.
I enable the "Static Application Switcher", resolve any potential conflicts by setting the setting for "Static Application Switcher". 
Now you can tweak the switcher by clicking on it. I have changed alt-tab and shift-alt-tab to "Next window (All windows)" and "Prev window (All windows)".

Experiment to find the settings that work best for you. It you want to go back to the poriginal settings, simply disable the Static Application Switcher and enable the key bindings in "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" again.

Comment: That works!  I also tried XFCE.  The taskbar is in the right location and the alt+tab'ing works like I expect ( windows'esque).   I'm going XFCE route.